# How do you do a "dry run" with meteor update?

Tags: meteor

How do you do a "dry run" of meteor update so you can see the changes, rather than apply them?

Comment: You can easily revert the changes using git since they only change the .meteor/ directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. Copy the folder of your project and apply the update on the copy to see how the changes.

You can also apply patches fixes that will not break your application, etc. See more in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteorupdate).

*Using Google Translate.*